# Python data classes. Can't use arguments as elements in list

Tags: python, struct, python-dataclasses, python-class

So I just stumbled upon python data classes after looking for something like a struct from the C-family. It's just that I don't understand why you can't do stuff like this:

```py
@dataclass
class Player:
    gridx: float
    gridy: float
    rotation: float
    pos = [gridx, gridy]

player = Player(2.5, 5.5, PI)
```

It says that `gridx` is not defined. Maybe I've just understood structs wrong and you can't even do this in languages like C. I thought it would just be similar to the `__init__` method in normal python classes where you could do pretty much whatever you want.

Comment: "Maybe I've just understood structs wrong and you can't even do this in languages like C." Indeed you cannot. I also don't understand what the *intended effect* is. "I thought it would just be similar to the __init__ method in normal python classes where you could do pretty much whatever you want." Okay, but "do whatever you want" *to what object"? Within `__init__`, there is a `self` that can be manipulated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to define `pos` as a `@property` which always returns a list of the current x, y values. You can't do that at class definition time, because no ***values*** exist yet at that time.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from math import pi

@dataclass
class Player:
    gridx: float
    gridy: float
    rotation: float

    @property
    def pos(self):
        return [self.gridx, self.gridy]

player = Player(2.5, 5.5, pi)
print(player.pos)
```

output

```
[2.5, 5.5]
```

It's up to you if you want to allow setting `pos` in order to change `gridx` and `gridy` (i.e. `@pos.setter`)

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Data classes more or less make easier to write this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, gridx, gridy, rotation):
        self.gridx = gridx
        self.gridy = gridy
        self.rotation = rotation
```

without repeating yourself all them time. I assume that by the time you write the data function gridx and gridy aren't yet defined. Though what you could do is use a **post_init** function to deal with that:

```
@dataclass
class Player:
    gridx: float
    gridy: float
    rotation: float

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.pos = [self.gridx, self.gridy]

player = Player(2.5, 5.5, math.pi)
print(player.pos)
```

As the name implies it's a function that is applied post (after) the dataclass has been rewritten as the above.

Comment: Wow, I'm learning new stuff all the time. That post init method seems useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Goby You might want to check what your actual requirements are here, because while both approaches above are correct, they have very different behavior!  In the first answer, where `pos` is a property, calculated from gridx and gridy when called, if you change gridx and gridy after instantiating a `Player` then `pos` will reflect that.  However in the second case it wont - `pos` will not change if you change gridx and gridy later on, but will need to be updated explicitly. ...again both approaches are correct, but have very different subsequent behavior!

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for clarifying! I ended up using the first approach with the ```@property``` decorator.